# How to reduce size of nodejs container which contains python utility

Tags: python, node.js, docker, dockerfile

I have javascript application, in which I use python utility (canconvert of canmatrix utility).
In javascript I call canconvert through

```
    execSync(`canconvert\\
                      --jsonExportAll\\
                      --jsonNativeTypes\\
                      --additionalFrameAttributes\\
                      --additionalSignalAttributes\\
                      ${dbcFileLocation} ${parsedJsonLocation}`);
```

so, canconvert should be available in the docker environment.
for now, I just install canmatrix through pip but size of the container becomes very big.

```
FROM node:10.15.3-slim AS dist
...
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y python python-pip && \
    pip install canmatrix && \
    chmod +x /entrypoint.sh

ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Python is not tiny.  Batteries included.

I guess you could try building your python code with nuitka or cython, but then you might end up giving up on automatic upgrades.

Disk is cheap - why not just use it like you have it?